# Convert AVPlayerItem to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, avplayeritem

I am trying to achieve a simple task like converting a `UIImage` to `NSData`, for `AVPlayerItem` that is returned to me when I select a video from the `PHImageManager`. What might be an equivalent of the `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to convert video in data:

```
PHVideoRequestOptions *videoRequestOptions = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
videoRequestOptions.deliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeAutomatic;
videoRequestOptions.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestPlayerItemForVideo:asset options:videoRequestOptions resultHandler:^(AVPlayerItem *item, NSDictionary *info)
            {
                //?
            }];
```

Whereas the `UIImage` goes like this:

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:imageRequestOptions resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info)
{
     NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(result)]; //<==THIS
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Aziz naah I didn't. I had to use something different.

Comment: I found a solution , I'll post it maybe some one will need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to get the URL from the AVPlayerItem asset, then create NSData from that URL:

```
PHAsset *asset = ...
PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestPlayerItemForVideo:asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVPlayerItem * _Nullable playerItem, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                NSURL *fileURL = [(AVURLAsset *)playerItem.asset URL];
                NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
                NSLog(@"tmpData Size: %lu",tmpData.length);
}];
```

and another way is to use 'requestAVAssetForVideo:asset' ....

```
PHFetchOptions *fetchOption = [[PHFetchOptions alloc]init];
if ([fetchOption respondsToSelector:@selector(setFetchLimit:)]) {
    [fetchOption setFetchLimit:1];
}
PHAsset *asset = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[@"<Video-localIdentifier>"] options:fetchOption].firstObject;
PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc]init];
options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;
options.deliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeAutomatic;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset
                                                options:options
                                          resultHandler:
 ^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
     AVURLAsset *urlAsset = (AVURLAsset *)asset;
     NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlAsset.URL];

     if (videoData) {
         NSLog(@"videoData Size: %lu", videoData.length);
     }

 }];
```

Comment: Getting them back out...?